# Scraping the next pages using Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am new to Python and I am trying to scrape some article links from a website. I managed to scrape the info needed from the first page but I don't know how to do the same for all the next pages. I know that there are quite a few posts regarding this issue but I wasn't able to figure it out in my case. The code that I am using is this one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['date', 'link'])

base_url = 'https://www.khaleejtimes.com'
search_url = 'https://www.khaleejtimes.com/search&text=&content=articles&datefilter=24hours&sort=oldest&facet.filter=TaxonomyLeaf:Coronavirus%20outbreak'

def get_info(article):
    date = article.find('div', class_= 'author_date').text
    print(date)
    link = base_url + article.find('a')['href']
    print(link)

source = requests.get(search_url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

results = soup.find(class_= 'search_listing')

for article in results.find_all('li'):
    get_info(article)

    print()

    csv_writer.writerow([date, link])

csv_file.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the next url?

Comment: At the bottom of the results in the webpage, there are 10 pages and an arrow that goes to next page. I suppose I need to use this arrow to go to the next page.

Comment: that wuld be a good strategy

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: in this spesific case there looks to be 10 pages of results. you culd nest your current code in a forloop and ad the page number to the end of your searchurl `&pagenumber=1` just change the pagenumber for each iteration

Comment: No, there will be much more than 10 pages. I am just trying the code at a smaller scale

Comment: then you need to fetch the last number of that list in the bottom.
it looks as it lists the lastpagenumber there

Comment: then you need to fetch the last number of that list in the bottom.
it looks as it lists the lastpagenumber there